# Problem with sync of offline database editing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sqlite, offline

I'm using offline database editing and I have managed to to save the data that I want and edit as an SQLite file, but how do I enable to sync option?

It doesn't seem to work in both the offline and online versions.

Comment: What database are you using and what QGIS version? Do you get any error message? You only have two options with the offline editing extension. When you have done your work you just hit synchronise and its done.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above, either the 'Convert to offline project' **OR** 'Synchronise' option is available at any one time.

If the 'Synchronise' option is greyed out then the database layer in your QGIS project should already be connected to the database and there is no need to Sync. If you hover your mouse over the layer it will pop-up with it's path/host.

[image]

*You can also right-click the layer to open the properties. In the general tab you will find the same information.*

If the database location is showing an SQLite file stored locally as below, and the synchronise option is not available then somehow your QGIS project has 'lost' that this is an offline edit of your database.

[image]

To repair you would need to make another offline edit to an SQLite file, **taking care not to overwrite the one with the edits you want to synchronise**. Make a note of the long numbers that are added to the end of the database name, and which number relates to which.

[image]

Then close QGIS and open the .qgs project file in a text editor, like WordPad, and find and replace instances of the new number with the number of the SQLite file that you want to sync.